# Amazon AWS SDK in Cakephp 3

Tags: php, amazon-s3, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to use the PHP AWS SDK in Cakephp 3. Before that, I followed the tutorial from Codecourse (in plain php) on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkSIBeS_M7w). Everything worked fine and I could get along with the tutorial.

For the Cakephp 3 project I used older code (http://www.bitsntricks.com/amazon-s3-services-cakephp/ link in step 1). Obviously, this Cakephp 2 code doesn't work out of the box in cakephp 3.  I'm fairly new to Cakephp and don't have a clue how to get this working (except that I need to adjust the code to V3 of AWS). My question is if somebody could give me any directions how to use AWS as a component in Cakephp 3?

I installed the PHP AWS SDK with composer and it seems that it recognizes the dependency but I do get an empty object when I call the S3Client::Factory method in the constructor.

Thanks in advance,
Mark

Code from tutorial in Cakephp 2 in combination with AWS v3:

```
<?php
 require 'aws/aws-autoloader.php';
 use Aws\Common\Exception\RuntimeException;
 use Aws\Common\Exception\MultipartUploadException;
 use Aws\S3\Model\MultipartUpload\UploadBuilder;
 use Aws\S3\S3Client;

 class AwsComponent  extends Component {
     public $bucket = '';
     private $s3 = null;

     public function __construct(){

         $this->s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
                      'key' => 'YOUR_API_KEY',
                      'secret' => 'YOUR_API_SECRET',
                      'region' => 'eu-west-1',
         ));
     }
 }
```

Comment: you need to post code not just links to tutorials

Comment: You are asking to do it for you, not to help you. You probably missunderstood the scope of this community...

Comment: Beg my pardon but I'm sure I'm not the only one struggling with this. Besides that, it is not appropriate to use require in any cakephp 3 files right?

Comment: I would recommend that you have a look at the CakePHP 3 docs on [**how to create components**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html#creating-a-component). On a side note, manually fiddling with autoloaders isn't required, composer will take care of that.

Comment: Ok thanks. So if I install a dependency with composer it is automatically reachable from anywhere in the project?

Comment: Anywhere after the inclusion of the composer autoloader in your applications bootstrap file, yes. **https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.2.0/config/bootstrap.php#L23**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally came up with the solution which is actually quite easy.

```
<?php
 namespace App\Controller\Component;
 use Cake\Controller\Component;
 use Aws\S3\S3Client;

 class AwsComponent extends Component{
    public $config = null;
    public $s3 = null;

    public function initialize(array $config){
        parent::initialize($config);
        $this->config = [
           's3' => [
               'key' => 'YOUR_KEY',
               'secret' => 'YOUR_SECRET',
               'bucket' => 'YOUR_BUCKET',
           ]
        ];
        $this->s3 = S3Client::factory([
            'credentials' => [
               'key' => $this->config['s3']['key'],
               'secret' => $this->config['s3']['secret']
            ],
        'region' => 'eu-central-1',
        'version' => 'latest'
        ]);
    }
}
```

In your controller e.g. you can do now:

```
class UsersController extends AppController{
    public $components = ['Aws'];

    public function example(){
         $objects = $this->Aws->s3->getIterator('ListObjects', [
                'Bucket' => $this->Aws->config['s3']['bucket']
        ]);
    }
 }
```

There must be said that it maybe isn't a good idea to make the configs public but that is up to you ;).

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /path/to/cakephp
composer require aws/aws-sdk-php

export AWS_S3_BUCKET=your-bucket-name;
export AWS_S3_REGION=ap-northeast-1;
export AWS_S3_KEY=YourAccesskeyID;
export AWS_S3_SECRET=YourSecretAccesskey;

define('STORAGE_PATH', ROOT . '/storage');
bin/cake bake component S3Client';

namespace App\Controller\Component;

namespace App\Controller\Component;

use Cake\Controller\Component;
use Cake\Controller\ComponentRegistry;
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;


 class S3ClientComponent extends Component
{
protected $_defaultConfig = [];

protected $default_bucket;

public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->s3 = S3Client::factory([
        'credentials' => [
            'key' => env('AWS_S3_KEY', ''),
            'secret' => env('AWS_S3_SECRET', ''),
        ],
        'region' => env('AWS_S3_REGION', ''),
        'version' => 'latest',
    ]);

    $this->default_bucket = env('AWS_S3_BUCKET', '');
}

/**
 * Get a list of files
 * @param string $bucket_name
 * @param string $dir
 * @param int $get_max
 * @return array
 * @see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_listObjects
 */
public function getList($bucket_name=null, $dir=null, $get_max=100)
{
    try {
        if(!$bucket_name) $bucket_name = $this->default_bucket;
        $list_obj = $this->s3->listObjects([
            'Bucket' => $bucket_name,
            'MaxKeys' => $get_max,
            'Prefix' => $dir
        ]);

        foreach ($list_obj['Contents'] as $file) {
            if (mb_substr($file['Key'], -1) !== "/" && (!$dir  || ($dir && strpos($file['Key'], sprintf('%s/', $dir)) !== false))) {
                $result[] = $file['Key'];
            }
        }

        return $result;
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

/**
 * Uploading files
 * @param string $file_path
 * @param string $store_path
 * @param string $bucket_name
 * @return mixed
 * @see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#putobject
 */
public function putFile($file_path, $store_path, $bucket_name=null)
{
    try {
        if(!$bucket_name) $bucket_name = $this->default_bucket;
        $result = $this->s3->putObject(array(
            'Bucket'       => $bucket_name,
            'Key'          => $store_path,
            'SourceFile'   => $file_path,
        ));

        return $result;
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

/**
 * File download
 * @param string $s3_file_path
 * @param string $store_dir_path
 * @param string $bucket_name
 * @return mixed
 * @see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrieveObjSingleOpPHP.html
 */
public function getFile($s3_file_path, $store_file_path, $bucket_name=null)
{
    try {
        if(!$bucket_name) $bucket_name = $this->default_bucket;
        $result = $this->s3->getObject([
            'Bucket' => $bucket_name,
            'Key'    => $s3_file_path,
            'SaveAs' => $store_file_path
        ]);

        return $result;
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

/**
 * Directory download (Recursive download)
 * @param string $s3_dir_path
 * @param string $local_dir_path
 * @param string $bucket_name
 */
public function getDirectory($s3_dir_path, $local_dir_path, $bucket_name=null)
{
    try {
        if(!$bucket_name) $bucket_name = $this->default_bucket;
        $file_list = $this->getList($bucket_name, $s3_dir_path);
        $this->chkDirHandle($file_list, $local_dir_path);
        foreach ($file_list as $from_path) {
            $to_path = sprintf('%s/%s', $local_dir_path, $from_path);
            $this->getFile($from_path, $to_path);
        }
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

/**
 * Copying files
 * @param string $s3_file_path
 * @param string $s3_copy_file_path
 * @param string $bucket_name_from
 * @param string $bucket_name_to
 * @return mixed
 * @see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingPHP.html
 */
public function copyFile($s3_file_path, $s3_copy_file_path, $bucket_name_from=null, $bucket_name_to=null)
{
    try {
        if(!$bucket_name_from) $bucket_name_from = $this->default_bucket;
        if(!$bucket_name_to) $bucket_name_to = $this->default_bucket;
        $result = $this->s3->copyObject(array(
            'Bucket'     => $bucket_name_to,
            'Key'        => $s3_copy_file_path,
            'CopySource' => sprintf('%s/%s', $bucket_name_from, $s3_file_path),
        ));

        return $result;
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

/**
 * Copy directory (Recursive copy)
 * @param string $s3_from_dir
 * @param string $s3_to_dir
 * @param string $bucket_name_from
 * @param string $bucket_name_to
 */
public function copyDirectory($s3_from_dir, $s3_to_dir, $bucket_name_from=null, $bucket_name_to=null)
{
    try {
        if(!$bucket_name_from) $bucket_name_from = $this->default_bucket;
        if(!$bucket_name_to) $bucket_name_to = $this->default_bucket;
        $file_list = $this->getList($bucket_name_from, $s3_from_dir);

        foreach ($file_list as $from_path) {
            $to_path = sprintf('%s/%s', $s3_to_dir, basename($from_path));
            $this->copyFile($from_path, $to_path);
        }
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

/**
 * Moving files
 * @param $s3_from_path
 * @param $s3_to_path
 * @return bool|mixed
 */
public function moveFile($s3_from_path, $s3_to_path)
{
    try {
        $result = false;
        if($this->copyFile($s3_from_path, $s3_to_path)) {
            $result = $this->deleteFile($s3_from_path);
        }

        return $result;
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

/**
 * Move directory (Recursive movement)
 * @param string $s3_from_dir
 * @param string $s3_to_dir
 * @param string null $bucket_name
 */
public function moveDirectory($s3_from_dir, $s3_to_dir, $bucket_name=null)
{
    try {
        if(!$bucket_name) $bucket_name = $this->default_bucket;
        $file_list = $this->getList($bucket_name, $s3_from_dir);
        foreach ($file_list as $from_path) {
            $to_path = sprintf('%s/%s', $s3_to_dir, basename($from_path));
            $this->moveFile($from_path, $to_path);
        }
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

/**
 * Delete files
 * @param string $file_path
 * @param string $bucket_name
 * @return mixed
 * @see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeletingMultipleObjectsUsingPHPSDK.html
 */
public function deleteFile($file_path, $bucket_name=null)
{
    try {
        if(!$bucket_name) $bucket_name = $this->default_bucket;
        $result = $this->s3->deleteObject(array(
            'Bucket' => $bucket_name,
            'Key'    => $file_path
        ));

        return $result;
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

/**
 * Delete directory (Remove recursively)
 * @param string $dir_name
 * @param string $bucket_name
 * @return mixed
 * @see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeletingMultipleObjectsUsingPHPSDK.html
 * @see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#deleteobjects
 */
public function deleteDirectory($dir_name, $bucket_name=null)
{
    try {
        if(!$bucket_name) $bucket_name = $this->default_bucket;
        $file_list = $this->getList($bucket_name, $dir_name);
        $files = $this->createArrayMultipleObjects($file_list);

        $result = $this->s3->deleteObjects(array(
            'Bucket'  => $bucket_name,
            'Delete' => [
                'Objects' => $files
            ]
        ));

        return $result;
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

/**
 * Convert from file list to array for multiple objects
 * @param $file_list
 * @return array
 */
private function createArrayMultipleObjects($file_list)
{
    foreach ($file_list as $name) {
        $files[] = array('Key' => $name);
    }
    return $files;
}

/**
 * Recursively check the path directories in the file list
 * @param $file_list
 */
private function chkDirHandle($file_list, $local_dir_path)
{
    foreach ($file_list as $filename) {
        $local_path = sprintf('%s/%s', $local_dir_path, dirname($filename));
        $this->chkDir($local_path);
    }
}
/**
 * Confirm existence of directory and create it if it does not exist.
 * @param $local_dir_path
 */
private function chkDir($local_dir_path)
{
    if(!file_exists($local_dir_path)) {
        mkdir($local_dir_path, 0777, true);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This code working for me properly

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;

class S3Controller extends AppController
{
protected $storage_path;

public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('S3Client');
    $this->autoRender = false;

    $this->storage_path = STORAGE_PATH;
}

public function getList()
{
    $file_list = $this->S3Client->getList(null);
    print_r($file_list); exit;
}

public function upload()
{
    $file_name = "test.txt";
    $store_dir = "ddd/";

    $file_local_path = sprintf('%s/%s', $this->storage_path, $file_name);
    $file_store_path = sprintf('%s%s', $store_dir, $file_name);

    $result = $this->S3Client->putFile($file_local_path, $file_store_path);
}

public function download()
{
    $file_name = "test.png";
    $s3_dir = "";
    $store_dir = sprintf('%s/d', $this->storage_path);

    $s3_file_path = sprintf('%s%s', $s3_dir, $file_name);
    $store_file_path = sprintf('%s/%s', $store_dir, $file_name);

    $file_obj = $this->S3Client->getFile($s3_file_path, $store_file_path);
}

public function downloadDirectory()
{
    $s3_dir = "cp";
    $local_dir = "dl";
    $local_dir_path = sprintf('%s/%s', $this->storage_path, $local_dir);
    $this->S3Client->getDirectory($s3_dir, $local_dir_path);
}

public function copy()
{
    $file_name = "test.png";
    $s3_dir = "";
    $s3_copy_dir = "cp/";

    $s3_file_path = sprintf('%s%s', $s3_dir, $file_name);
    $s3_copy_file_path = sprintf('%s%s', $s3_copy_dir, $file_name);

    $this->S3Client->copyFile($s3_file_path, $s3_copy_file_path);
}

public function copyDirectory()
{
    $s3_from_dir = "cp";
    $s3_to_dir = "cp_d";
    $this->S3Client->copyDirectory($s3_from_dir, $s3_to_dir);
}

public function move()
{
    $file_name = "test.png";
    $s3_from_dir = "cp/";
    $s3_to_dir = "mv/";
    $s3_from_path = sprintf('%s%s', $s3_from_dir, $file_name);
    $s3_to_path = sprintf('%s%s', $s3_to_dir, $file_name);
    $this->S3Client->moveFile($s3_from_path, $s3_to_path);
}

public function moveDirectory()
{
    $s3_from_dir = "mv";
    $s3_to_dir = "mv_d";
    $this->S3Client->moveDirectory($s3_from_dir, $s3_to_dir);
}

public function delete()
{
    $s3_file_path = 'cp/test.png';
    $this->S3Client->deleteFile($s3_file_path);
}

public function deleteDirectory()
{
    $s3_dir_path = 'cp';
    $this->S3Client->deleteDirectory($s3_dir_path);
}
}
```

Comment: This code working for me properly